# Given set of grammar rules, how to find if they correspond to Context-free or unrestricted

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata, context-free

Given set of grammar rules, how to find if they correspond to Context-free or unrestricted?

Just for Understanding (don't solve the below one),
eg:

\begin{align}
S &\rightarrow B/A, \\
1B &\rightarrow 111B, \\
1A0 &\rightarrow 00
\end{align}

Comment: Since it is undecidable to check if a set of grammar rues is context-free or not, there is no algorithm to accomplish the task. That is, it will forever be an art or research to understand or find whether they are context-free or not, although we might increase our heuristic indefinitely.

Comment: @vamsikrishna Is your question about whether a set of rules qualifies *syntactically* as valid CFG rules or whether they are *equivalent* to a CFG? (In the latter case, refer to Apass.Jack's comment.)

Answer (score 1):

It is undecidable to determine whether the *language* generated by a given grammar has a context-free grammar.

However, if you are simply asking whether a *grammar* itself is context-free, look no further than the left hand side of each production. A grammar is context free iff the left hand side of each production is a single non-terminal.